# TextView with different Colors, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, textview, uikit

I have a textView and a String.

I would like to add this string with some attribute (Red color and bold font), but I would also like to keep the textView default font color to black if a user type in.

I'm trying to achieve this with `NSAttributedString` but since i dont know the text before this String i cant find a way to reach my goal. (I'm not gonna post some code since i'm only trying not working stuff with `NSAttributedString`)

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can change the `typingAttributes` of the `UITextView` in order to force the black color each time. Coloring yourself the rest of the string in red/bold when needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
        let rangeMain = (textView!.text! as NSString).range(of: (textView!.text! as NSString) as String)
        let rangeGreen = (textView!.text! as NSString).range(of: "a")
        let rangeBlue = (textView!.text! as NSString).range(of: "b")
        let rangeGray = (textView!.text! as NSString).range(of: "c")
        
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textView!.self.text!)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.black, range: rangeMain)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.blue, range: rangeBlue)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.green, range: rangeGreen)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.gray, range: rangeGray)
        
        textView!.attributedText = attributedString
```

Did you try something like this?

It had to change the specific text (characters: a,b,c which you can rename you need to be)...